# SQL Query, Get list of range conflicts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help creating my query and would be grateful if someone could help.

I have got a staff time entry website.
The website saves the start and end times of their work.

They can enter a few different times on the same day as long as these times are not overclocking other than their entered times.

For example, if they clocked from 08:00 AM to 12:00 PM.
Their second entry mustn't be between these times.

I have a formula which checks two different ranges.

**Max(start1,start2) < Min(end1,end2)**

So, I would like to implement this formula in my database.

for Example

| EmployeeID | SelectedDate | StartTimeValue | EndTimeValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 | 15 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 | 25 | 37 |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 | 35 | 40 |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 | 11 | 21 |

In the above entery last two is overclocking.

35 - 40 entry is worng because 35 is between 25-37, which is previously entered.
The 11- 21 entry is wrong because it covers the 15-20.

BASICALLY, I would like to know how to implement this formula in SQL
**Max(start1,start2) < Min(end1,end2)**

I Tried something like this but it didn't work

```
SELECT  
  T1.EmployeeID,T1.SelectedDate,T1.StartTimeValue,T1.EndTimeValue,
  T2.EmployeeID,T2.SelectedDate,T2.StartTimeValue,T2.EndTimeValue
FROM [adilsari_Test].[dbo].[EmployeeTimeSheetModel] T1
INNER JOIN [adilsari_Test].[dbo].[EmployeeTimeSheetModel] T2 ON T1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID 
 AND T1.TimeSheetID <> t2.TimeSheetID 
 AND  T1.SelectedDate = T2.SelectedDate
WHERE (SELECT MAX(v) FROM(VALUES (T1.StartTimeValue,T2.StartTimeValue)) AS value(v))>10 AND MIN(T1.EndTimeValue,T2.EndTimeValue)
```

Comment: Can you include what your expected output would be?

Comment: Can you include why "... but it didn't work" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for overlaping ranges, in this case you can refer to [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap), a query would be like :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp

SELECT 1 EmployeeID,'2022-10-10'    SelectedDate,1  StartTimeValue,10   EndTimeValue
INTO #Temp
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2022-10-10',15, 20
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2022-10-10',25, 37
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2022-10-10',35, 40
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'2022-10-10',11, 21

SELECT *
FROM #Temp t
JOIN #Temp t1 ON t.SelectedDate = t1.SelectedDate AND t.StartTimeValue <> t1.StartTimeValue AND t.EndTimeValue <> t1.EndTimeValue
WHERE (t.StartTimeValue <= t1.EndTimeValue)  AND  (t.EndTimeValue >= t1.StartTimeValue)
```